# A graph is distance transitive iff it is vertex transitive

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, group-actions

A graph is distance transitive, if 
$\forall x,y,u,v \in V \ \text{so that}\ \  d(x,y)=d(u,v)$
there exists $g \in Aut(G)$ so that $g(x)=u$ and $g(y)=v$.

$G$ is vertex transitive if $\forall x,y\in V$ the is some $g \in Aut(G)$ so that $g(x)=y$

*I want to prove that:*
$G$ is distance transitive $\iff$ $G$ is vertex transitive and a stabilizer of a point over $Aut(G)$ has $diam(G)+1$ orbits.

Could you help me with where to begin?

Comment: It's hard to help you if you do not know the definitions involved in what you are trying to prove! Fix a vertex $v$ and let $H$ be its stabilizer in ${\rm Aut}(V)$, and let $d = {\rm diam}(V)$.. Then, for $0 \le s \le d$ the vertices at  distance $s$ from $v$ clearly form a union of orbits of $H$. There are exactly $d+1$ orbits of $H$  if and only if, for each $s$, there is only one such orbit, which is equivalent to ${\rm Aut}(G)$ being distance transitive.